# Read the compressed or zipped response data in java

Tags: java, spring, performance, servlets, httpresponse

I am trying to read the data from responsedata in java.  The data was set in response body. But how can I read the data from response in my code.

```
The below code is for used for setting the compressed or zipped the data. The objective is to read this response data into string. 

writeBytes(byte[] responseData, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String contentType) throws IOException {
.......some code 
.......some code

ByteArrayOutputStream contentBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    byte[] responseData;
    responseData = GzipHelper.compressGZIP(responseData);
    int contentLength1 = contentBytes.size();

response.setContentLength(contentLength1);
contentBytes.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
}

Where 
public static byte[] compressGZIP(byte[] data1) throws IOException {
ByteArrayOutputStream os1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzipp = new GZIPOutputStream(os1);
byte[] arg;
try {
gzipp.write(data1);
gzipp.finish();
arg = os1.toByteArray();
} finally {
    }

///////////

Now I have to read this zipped or compressed data. I can see that when I check value of response.getoutputstream() it is showing me data in some encrypted format. But how can I  unzipped or uncompressed response data and convert it into more meaningful response or in readable string? The objective is to read actual response body data (real body) that has been set.     Please advice.
```

Comment: (1) That code won't compile unless there's a `return arg;` and another `}` at the end of `compressGZIP`. (2) If there is, the data you get back is not encrypted, it is compressed with gzip -- as you directed. **To get the original uncompressed form, decompress the compressed form.**

Comment: Yes http://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085, it is there. I had not added the complete code. I was asking how to get the original uncompressed data.

Comment: Yes http://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085, it is there. I had not added the complete code. My question is how to get the original uncompressed data back into string.

Comment: can someone please help on this. how to retrieve data.